# How can i #include <pthread.h> windows, linker option?

Tags: multithreading, gcc

How can i include `pthread.h`on windows? I try compile with `-lpthread` but it doesnt work.
I am using `GCC C compiler`. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having GCC isn't enough, as pthreads is a part of POSIX platforms, which Windows isn't. You'll have to try to use the Windows thread API, download a pthread library for Windows, or compile in a POSIX environment (Cygwin, MinGW).

Comment: Thank you, what windiws api do you recommend?

Comment: When I googled "windows threading" the first link seemed to get me on a good trajectory. Downvote.

Comment: @hicaemic <windows.h>

Comment: I dont care about your downvote, its normal on this site, only downvote, i must register evry times new account. I like haters like you..